# Tab Panel in Panel

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am trying to place a TabPanel in my panel. The TabPanel appears but the functionality is broken. It displays both the tab's content at the same time and clicking the different tabs does nothing. This is how i am adding my tabpanel

```
var tabPanel = 
        Ext.create('Ext.TabPanel', {
            fullscreen: true,
            layout: 'fit',
            defaults: {
                styleHtmlContent: true
            },


            items: [
                {
                    title: 'Home',
                    html: 'Home Screen'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Contact',
                    html: 'Contact Screen'
                }
            ]
        });
this.add([ topToolbar, tabPanel, bottomToolbar ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

solved it missing

```
fullscreen: true,
```